# Fetch request returns objects that don't match predicate when relationship is updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is driving me crazy, please help :)

My model has an entity `NewsItem` with a relationship `source` to a `NewsSource` entity. `NewsSource` has a property `BOOL subscribed`.

I am using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to display all `NewsItem` objects that match the predicate `source.subscribed == YES`.

The problem occurs when I edit the `subscribed` property of a `NewsSource` in another view controller and `save` the context. Of course, the fetched results controller doesn't pick up the change, because no `NewsItem` object was actually updated. That's why I register for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` to call `performFetch` and `reloadData` when the `notification.userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]` contains a `NewsSource` object.

Hope that's all clear, feel free to comment on this approach as well ;)

So what's just weird is that the fetched results controller's `performFetch` **does not return the correct `NewsItem` objects** that match the predicate. Using explicit fetch requests, I tracked it down to the following:

```
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"NewsItem"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"source.subscribed == YES"];
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
    for (NewsItem *item in result) {
        NSLog(@"source.subscribed = %d", item.source.subscribed); // logs "source.subscribed = 0" when I change the value, although the predicate filters for YES!
    }
}
```

Although I use the predicate to filter the query, items with `subscribed == NO` are returned! When I query the `NewsSource` objects directly, it works as expected:

```
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"NewsSource"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subscribed == YES"];
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
    for (NewsSource *source in result) {
        NSLog(@"subscribed = %d", source.subscribed); // always (correctly) logs "subscribed = 1"
    }
}
```

**Do you have any ideas what happens here?**

I might add that I am using a Core Data setup with RestKit, so there is a private queue `persistentStoreManagedObjectContext` with a direct connection to the database and its child context `mainQueueManagedObjectContext`. I am only using the `mainQueueManagedObjectContext` and `save` that one. On `applicationWillResignActive` the `persistentStoreManagedObjectContext` is saved. When I quit and restart the app, the fetched results controllers displays the correct results.

Comment: What context does the other viewController use? Are the changes saved all the way down to the persistent store?

Comment: I use the `mainQueueManagedObjectContext` all the way through and only save to the persistent store in the App Delegate. Fetches on the `mainQueueManagedObjectContext` should not depend on the `persistentStoreManagedObjectContext` and should yield the correct results anyway. The `managedObjectContext` both view controllers use is definitely the same, that was the first thing I checked ;) In fact, I only register to the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` of the `mainQueueManagedObjectContext` by passing it as the `object` parameter.

Comment: I found highly weird behavior with nested contexts had a lot to do with `awakeFromInsert` getting called twice.  Don't use awakeFromInsert if your MOCs have parents.  Consider it deprecated.

Comment: But that sounds like not your issue.  The other thing I'm finding is that the mainQueueConcurrency means that some things are deferred until the next runloop iteration, so maybe try to queue your `performFetch` with a `performBlock` on the MOC, even the mainQueue